# How to check the 'health' of the main board without a thermal camera?

Tags: creality-ender-3, electronics, safety, maintenance

Given that the main board gets warm, potentially wearing out the electronics, how do I check the 'health' of a main board without having a thermal camera?

As I understand it could be most easily spotted using a thermal camera are there other ways of checking the 'health' or 'safety' of the main board?

Comment: do you mean detecting burnt out connectors etc?

Comment: @Trish yes, and methods of detecting other indicators of potential deterioration.

Comment: huh... aside from "Stuff doesn't work" that is, right? (because that is obvious^^)

Comment: Yes, more for preventative and maintenance. Such as for example inspecting the board of a second hand printer that works. But to measure, get an idea of the quality or safety and perhaps spot potential failure points or safety issues early.